# What realmd_tags parameter in sssd config is used for?

Tags: sssd

I have multiples linux workstations using sssd to authenticated with ad.
To avoid misconfiguration ansible is used to maintain homogeneous setup of sssd.

There come my interrogation what is the parameter realmd_tags in the domain section of sssd used for.
Man page tells me:

```
realmd_tags (string)

    Various tags stored by the realmd configuration service for this domain.
```

Given that I could not find any references to tags in the realm command documentation that is not very helpfull.

On the net you can find tons of exemples of sssd configs with either

```
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
```

But no comments on the purpose of it.
To make it short what can I put in this field and what can break if I do not do it properly?
This is more out of curiosity than anything else as either of the above setups works and I suspect this parameter to be just a label of some sort. But sometimes stupid question can teach you something and prevent disasters.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar question and curiousity.  This led me to github and reviewing code for SSSD, however it was the realmd codebase that has the answer.

From https://github.com/freedesktop/realmd/search?q=realmd_tags

```
        value = realm_ini_config_get (self->pv->config, self->pv->section, "realmd_tags");
        if (value && strstr (value, "manages-system"))
            manages_system = TRUE;
        g_free (value);
```

There doesn't appear to be any other code that gets the `"realmd_tags"` configuration.
There is code that creates its own realmd_tags, e.g:
https://github.com/freedesktop/realmd/blob/63a6453399dddb3d49ec32e6095594ecc322829f/service/realm-sssd-ad.c#L183

```
    realmd_tags = g_string_new ("");
    if (realm_options_manage_system (options, disco->domain_name))
        g_string_append (realmd_tags, "manages-system ");
    g_string_append (realmd_tags, use_adcli ? "joined-with-adcli " : "joined-with-samba ");
```

This logic was introduced back in 2012 to handle automatic or one time passwords (and other scenarios), refer to commit:
https://github.com/freedesktop/realmd/commit/3a988441e411a8e38f668edf1114397e1726a155